# Pass db variable to function argument

Tags: go

I'm trying to parse some RSS feeds using Golang. A package I found was https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-pkg-rss

My process is

1. Get feeds from my Postgres DB
2. For each feed, fetch the articles
3. Store each article into the Postgres DB

My code is as below

```
func main() {
  db := dbConnect() // returns the DB connection variable

  feeds := getRssFeeds(db) // returns feeds from my DB
  for i := 0; i < len(feeds); i++ {
    getFeedArticles(feeds[i].url, 5, db)
  }
}

func getFeedArticles(uri string, timeout int, db *sql.DB) {
  // using the package to get RSS feed contents
  feed := rss.New(timeout, true, chanHandler, itemHandler)
  if err := feed.Fetch(uri, nil); err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "[e] %s: %s", uri, err)
    return
  }
}

func chanHandler(feed *rss.Feed, newchannels []*rss.Channel) {
  // no need to do anything...
}

func itemHandler(feed *rss.Feed, ch *rss.Channel, newitems []*rss.Item) {
  for i := 0; i < len(newitems); i++ {
    fmt.Println(newitems[i].Title)

    // insert the article into DB here
  }
}
```

How do I pass the `db` variable to `itemHandler` so I can insert the article into my DB? I suppose I could call `dbConnect()` to create a new `db` variable to insert, but that would seem wasteful.

Is there a better way to do this process?

Comment: http://go-database-sql.org/ may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use closures:

```
func makeHandler(db Database) rss.ItemHandler {
    return func(feed *rss.Feed, ch *rss.Channel, newitems []*rss.Item) {
         for i := 0; i < len(newitems); i++ {
             fmt.Println(newitems[i].Title)
             // Accessed via closure:
             db.InsertArticle(newitems[i])
         }
    }
}
```

Or some variation thereof. You can then call `rss.New` with `makeHandler(db)`, or define `itemHandler` in `getFeedArticle`... In any case, `itemHandler` will have `db` being defined and accessible.

[This tutorial](http://golang.org/doc/codewalk/functions/) and [this part of the specs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals) explain it in more details

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion of closure and called "makehandler(db)" in "rss.New" but I get "cannnot use makeHandler(db) (type handler) as type feeder.ItemHandler in function argument". Any ideas?

Comment: ok, instead of calling "makeHandler(db)" in rss.New, I did rss.New(timeout, true, chanHandler, func(feed *rss.Feed, ch *rss.Channel, newitems[]*rss.Item) { ... }) and this worked. Not sure why the first approach isn't working?

Comment: The first did not work because you provided a `handler` where a `feeder.ItemHandler` was expected, although they both refer to the same function signature. You can correct it by having `makeHandler` return a `feeder.ItemHandler` instead (it has the same signature). I only defined `handler` for clarity, but the correct way is to return a `ItemHandler` directly.

Comment: And indeed: https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-pkg-rss/blob/master/feed.go defines `type ItemHandler func(f *Feed, ch *Channel, newitems []*Item)` (i.e. same as `handler`)

Comment: I have edited the response so that it now returns the correct func type. Thank you for your feedback !